# Error using getline with ifstream - C++

Tags: c++, string, ifstream, getline

I need help, I tried googling if I could find a similar problem but the solutions for others didn't work for me.

I'm trying to use `getline()` to read the file I've opened but it's not accepting the parameters I've given it.

What I'm trying to accomplish at this time (not the entire program) is to open a `.csv` file and determine how many elements it has inside by using `getline()` and using the `,` character as the delimiter. My loop has an index which I could just add 1 to it so that I can get the total number of elements inside the file.

The reason I'm doing this is because I intend to use it for a project at school but so far I've gotten stuck at the `getline()` error:

> no matching function for call to 'std::basic_ifstream::getline(std::string&, int, const char [2])'

My code is here:

```
void readfile(string a)
{
    int i = 0;
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open(a.c_str());
    string temp;

    //count how many elements are inside
    if(infile.is_open())
    {
        while(infile.good())
        {
            infile.getline(temp, 256, ",");
            i++;
        }
        infile.close();
        i+=1;
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"Error opening file.";
    }
    cout<<i;
}
```

Comment: The delimiter is one character; use `','`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the free `getline()` function:

```
std::string line;
getline(infile, line);
```

Comment: Yep it does run using the free getline() function, however I needed the other getline function because of the delimiter. I used it as a basis to count the elements (plus I'll need to use it to individually extract data in the future parts of this program).

is there a different way to simulate the delimeter of getline so that I can use the free getline function?

Comment: Both member and non-member `getline`s have that parameter. Use [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) from now on. What it doesn't have is the maximum number of characters to be extracted.

Comment: I didn't notice that! thanks for the info. I tried it too but it went to the same error as what I had:  [Error] no matching function for call to 'getline(std::ifstream&, std::string&, const char [2])'. Could it be possible that it's my compiler or is it really the code? :/

Comment: @Kobowo swap the `","` for `'.'`. Reason is, with double quotes, this is a string literal, not a character literal, hence a '\0' is appended automatically and you get a `char[2]` array.

Comment: @iksemyonov Thanks it worked! I forgot to try using the '' after changing to the free getline function.. thanks for everyone's input!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer by @UlrichEckhardt, I'd handle delimiters like this:

```
if(infile.is_open())
{
    string temp;
        // std::getline(std;:istream&, std::string) used below
    while(getline(infile, temp)) {            
        std::stringstream stream(str);
        std::string token;
        while (std::getline(stream, token, ','))
        if (!token.empty()) // it's up to you to decide how to handle empty tokens
            i++;
    }
}
```

Note the `','`. If it were `"."`, this would be considered a string by the compiler, which is exactly what you're seeing in the error message: a `'\0'` is appended automatically, thus producing a `char[2]`.

Comment: Two mistakes: Firstly, `while(infile.good())` is just as bad as `while(!infile.eof())`. Second thing: Why bother closing the stream if the destructor does that automatically? Do you mistrust it that much?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I merely copied those parts form OP's post.